# SATA-USB cabled HDD not listed among storages drives

Tags: usb, mount, sata, cable

I replaced my laptop HDD by an SSD and bought a SATA-USB cable to use that HDD as an external storage. But unfortunately that HDD is not automatically listed among the "Devices and drives" list as would be a USB stick.

However the HDD is listed among the "Devices and printers" list and its properties indicate that it is recognized as a storage device... So I guess this has to deal with drivers

I just don't get why Windows isn't suggesting driver research automatically like for a new USB stick... Even the troubleshooting function doesn't offer to search for drivers...

I'm lost here, can you please help me and / or explain me a few things about drives mounting because I clearly lack of some knowledge in this domain... Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the *actual* problem? How it is listed or where seems irrelevant, at least on the surface. Doesn't it appear in disk management? An external USB HDD is different than a simple USB stick, behaves differently and is often interpreted differently by the OS, regardless of performing the exact some function.

Comment: @MichaelBay The actual problem is that I can't access the content of the HDD. Yes it appears in Disk Management. PS: Sorry for posting this as an answer, I'm just not allowed to post it as a comment

Comment: Looks like you have a registered and unregistered account -  you'd need to use the contact us link at the bottom of the page to request a merger of this account and https://superuser.com/users/899317/arnaud . This needs a CM or dev to do it. I've split up your answer as needed so we can convert it to comments.

Answer (score 0):

"SATA-USB cable to use that HDD as an external storage"
with the ones I have used to date: this has been plug and play. NO OTHER DRIVERS NEEDED.

"HDD is listed among the "Devices and printers" list"
did you select any windows options the first time the pop-up such as "use this device as a Chinese pit-bull terrier dog printer" or something?
Printers come with SD-Card readers so they can be detected when you plug a printer in, but a HDD...? Again, did you select "open printer dialogue" or similar when first connected?

**This sounds like you need some extra help from a Microsoft Utility:
DevCon**.  The DevCon utility is a command-line utility that acts as an alternative to Device Manager. Using DevCon, you can enable, disable, restart, update, remove, and query individual devices or groups of devices.

[DevCon](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon)

Have a read at a helpful link here:
https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P7bZSAS

Comment: Comment by the OP:  I expected it to be plug and play actually. No pop-up appeared when I plugged the HDD the first time, it just made the usual windows sound but no pop-up. And I did not select anything the first time I plugged so: no I did not select "open printer dialogue". Should I select this ? I will try DevCon thanks.